# How to know the current user identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In an mvc .net web application that uses forms authentication, how to know the current user identity in controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `User.Identity.Name`:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    string currentlyLoggedInUsername = User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.HttpContext.User.Identity
```

Note that you should also check if

```
  this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

to distinguish between anonymous and authenticated users.